# Materialize CSS framework hamburger menu not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, materialize

I'm trying to get the hamburger button for a mobile menu working on a materialize website, and I've followed the documentation, but for some reason when I click the button this happens:

[image: What it looks like when I tap on mobile]

But, when I go fullscreen I can clearly see the menu, like so.

[image: What it looks like when I expand the screen to maximum width after clicking on desktop]

Anyone have any idea what the problem is? This is the code I am using:

```
<nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <a href="" class="brand-logo">logo</a>
        <a href="" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
        <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
            <li><a href="">home</a></li>
<li><a href="">About</a></li>
<li><a href="">services</a></li>
<ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-demo">
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
</ul>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Also, I've initialized the JavaScript in a script below, and it's loading last.

```
<script>    
    $(".button-collapse").sideNav();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A snippet for my previous project

```
<!-- Navbar START-->
<nav>
  <div class="nav-wrapper bg__secondary">
     <a href="" class="brand-logo">logo</a>

    <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
    <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-demo">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large">Login</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<!-- Navbar END-->
```

I think you forgot to include the `$(".button-collapse").sideNav();` into a document ready function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // REQUIRED FOR BUTTON COLLAPSE
  $(".button-collapse").sideNav();
}
```

My material-css version: `"materialize-css": "^0.100.2"`, `"jquery": "3.2.1"`